# Fixed view in ViewPager's content layout, under CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

My app has an `Activity` with `TabLayout`, and 3 `Fragments`. In `Activity's` layout, I have `CoordinatorLayout` with `ViewPager`. I need to animate ***toolbar*** as well.
Now In Fragments layout, I need to put a fixed TextView at the bottom.
Given below is the `XML` of activity and fragment.

> I am facing the problem that this fixed `TextView` in Fragment's
>   layout is going under the bottom navigation bar and is scrolling also,
>   that I don't want.

How can achieve this ?

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/rlParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvConfirmOrder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkGreen"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/confirm_order"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you want this bottom fixed `TextView` for each fragment, it can be solved by transferring your `TextView` to `activity.xml` and adding a custom behavior to it.

So, **firstly**, create a class that represents custom behavior:

```
public class FixedBottomViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    public FixedBottomViewBehavior() {
    }

    public FixedBottomViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        //making our bottom view depends on ViewPager (or whatever that have appbar_scrolling_view_behavior behavior)
        return dependency instanceof ViewPager;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(parent)) {
            //attach our bottom view to the bottom of CoordinatorLayout
            child.setY(parent.getBottom() - child.getHeight());

            //set bottom padding to the dependency view to prevent bottom view from covering it
            dependency.setPadding(dependency.getPaddingLeft(), dependency.getPaddingTop(),
                    dependency.getPaddingRight(), child.getHeight());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

There is no magic here, we're just making our bottom view dependent on some view with `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` (in our case it's `ViewPager`) and then attaching it to the bottom of `CoordinatorLayout` and setting some padding to dependency.

**Secondly**, change your `activity.xml`, by adding your `TextView` there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/clMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvConfirmOrder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkGreen"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/confirm_order"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_behavior="your.package.name.FixedBottomViewBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Make sure you've removed your `TextView` from `fragment.xml`. Don't forget also to change `your.package.name.FixedBottomViewBehavior` to your package name exactly.

**Voila!** That should work like a charm with proper toolbar animation and fixed view at the bottom.

***In addition:*** if you don't know how to pass your `OnClick` event to your fragments you can follow this way in your `Activity`:

```
    public interface OnConfirmOrderClickListener {
        void onConfirmOrderClick(View v);
    }

    public Fragment getActiveFragment() {
        String name = makeFragmentName(pager.getId(), pager.getCurrentItem());
        return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(name);
    }

    public String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
    } 

    tvConfirmOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment current = getActiveFragment();
            if (current instanceof OnConfirmOrderClickListener)
                ((OnConfirmOrderClickListener) current).onConfirmOrderClick(v);
        }
    });
```

Don't forget to make your fragments `implements OnConfirmOrderClickListener`. Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: And what if the fixed view has to be in only one fragment of the viewpager ?

Comment: @VincentNOCK hide/show  the view according to which fragment currently on screen, using `onPageChangeListener` for `ViewPager`.

Comment: I made the button scroll with onPageChangeListener. I'll add an answer to explain how to do that

Comment: This solution is the most elegant. Thanks @rom4ek

Comment: @rom4ek Will the above solution work if I'm using an `EditText` instead of the `TextView` tvConfirmOrder? (The height of `EditText` changes according to the text entered.)

Answer (score 1):

For those who want the button to appear only in one fragment, it's possible to use `onPageChangeListener` of `ViewPager` to make the button scroll with the ViewPager

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        updateButtonPosition(position, positionOffsetPixels);
    }
});


//Move the button according to the tab you want it to be fixed. 
//Here is the 3rd tab of a 3 tab viewPager, for instance
private void updateButtonPosition(int position, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    int fixedRewardXPos;
    if (position == 0) {
        fixedRewardXPos = viewPager.getWidth() * 2 - positionOffsetPixels;
    } else if (position == 1) {
        fixedRewardXPos = viewPager.getWidth() - positionOffsetPixels;
    } else {
        fixedRewardXPos = -positionOffsetPixels;
    }

    //Add getLeft() to keep the button to its former position in it's fragment
    aButton.setX(fixedRewardXPos + aButton.getLeft());
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little explanation on the action performed on different position value?